# PL/SQL procedure not returning expected results

Tags: oracle, shell, plsql, sqlplus

I have a PL/SQL procedure that I am running within shell script.

I pulled the logic out but it is not running the inner BEGIN-END; part :

```
DECLARE
model_exists NUMBER(1);
BEGIN 
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO model_exists from mdsys.rdf_model$ WHERE model_name='XCLOVER';
  BEGIN 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE table SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_XCLOVER(RDF$STC_sub  VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF$STC_pred VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF$STC_obj VARCHAR(4000) not null)'; COMMIT;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL (TRIPLE SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S)'; COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -955 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_XCLOVER';
      END IF;
  END; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL ON SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL to MDSYS'; 
IF model_exists = 0 THEN
    SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('XCLOVER', 'XCLOVER_TPL','TRIPLE'); 
END IF;
COMMIT; 
END;
/
```

The way it is written in shell script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
. /etc/profile.d/oracle.sh

MODEL=$1

echo "DECLARE" > createxmodel.tmp
echo "model_exists NUMBER(1);" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "BEGIN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "SELECT COUNT(*) INTO model_exists from mdsys.rdf_model\$ WHERE model_name='$MODEL';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "BEGIN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE table SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_$MODEL(RDF\$STC_sub  VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF\$STC_pred VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF\$STC_obj VARCHAR(4000) not null)';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SEMANTIC.$MODEL""_TPL (TRIPLE SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S)'; " >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "EXCEPTION" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "WHEN OTHERS THEN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "IF SQLCODE != -955 THEN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.$MODEL""_TPL';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_$MODEL';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "END IF;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "END;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL ON SEMANTIC.$MODEL""_TPL to MDSYS';" >> createxmodel.tmp 
echo "IF model_exists = 0 THEN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('$MODEL', '$MODEL""_TPL','TRIPLE');" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "END IF;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "COMMIT;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "END;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "/" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "exit;" >> createxmodel.tmp

sqlplus -S user/password < createxmodel.tmp
```

the error it throws right now is:

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 15
```

which tells me that the inner BEGIN never get's executed...

This use to work :(

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you make sure that the able or view exists?

Comment: That's what the first BEGIN-END block of code is doing. It creates both tables and catches exception if any of them already exist. Then, when it get's to GRANT option, the table should be there.

Comment: Does `mdsys.rdf_model$` exist (and is it visible to the user account running the script)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd be better off putting each table's creation in its own BEGIN...END block, as in:

```
echo "DECLARE" > createxmodel.tmp
echo "  model_exists NUMBER(1);" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  excp_table_exists EXCEPTION;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(excp_table_exists, -955);" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "BEGIN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO model_exists from mdsys.rdf_model\$ WHERE model_name='$MODEL';" >> createxmodel.tmp

echo "  BEGIN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE table SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_$MODEL(RDF\$STC_sub  VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF\$STC_pred VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF\$STC_obj VARCHAR(4000) not null)';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  EXCEPTION" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "    WHEN excp_table_exists THEN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_$MODEL';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  END;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  BEGIN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SEMANTIC.$MODEL""_TPL (TRIPLE SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S)'; " >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  EXCEPTION" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "    WHEN excp_table_exists THEN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.$MODEL""_TPL';" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  END;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL ON SEMANTIC.$MODEL""_TPL to MDSYS';" >> createxmodel.tmp 
echo "  IF model_exists = 0 THEN" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "    SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('$MODEL', '$MODEL""_TPL','TRIPLE');" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  END IF;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "  COMMIT;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "END;" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "/" >> createxmodel.tmp
echo "exit;" >> createxmodel.tmp
```

Hopefully this will help.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

All you needed to do is to move the GRANT statement after you create-- no reason to have it outside of the block-- the error you were getting was from the editor, not an actual PL/SQL error, correct?

```
    DECLARE
    model_exists NUMBER(1);
    BEGIN 
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO model_exists from mdsys.rdf_model$ WHERE model_name='XCLOVER';
      BEGIN 
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE table SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_XCLOVER(RDF$STC_sub  VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF$STC_pred VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF$STC_obj VARCHAR(4000) not null)'; COMMIT;
          EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL (TRIPLE SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S)'; COMMIT;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL ON SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL to MDSYS';
          EXCEPTION
          WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF SQLCODE != -955 THEN
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL';
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_XCLOVER';
          END IF;
      END; 

    IF model_exists = 0 THEN
        SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('XCLOVER', 'XCLOVER_TPL','TRIPLE'); 
    END IF;
    COMMIT; 
    END;
```

Comment: What happened actually is that I have 2 CREATE statements and if one throws exception, it never executes the other CREATE TABLE statements. so when it get's to GRANT the table, it can't because the second CREATE statement never got executed.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example why proper Exception handling is important.
Probably if you had atleast a dbms_output, a lot of headasche would have been saved:

```
DECLARE
model_exists NUMBER(1);
BEGIN 
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO model_exists from mdsys.rdf_model$ WHERE model_name='XCLOVER';
  BEGIN 
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE table SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_XCLOVER(RDF$STC_sub  VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF$STC_pred VARCHAR(4000) not null,RDF$STC_obj VARCHAR(4000) not null)'; COMMIT;
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL (TRIPLE SDO_RDF_TRIPLE_S)'; COMMIT;
      EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Some error has occurred'):
      IF SQLCODE != -955 THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL';
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE SEMANTIC.RDF_STAGE_TABLE_XCLOVER';
      END IF;
  END; 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ALL ON SEMANTIC.XCLOVER_TPL to MDSYS'; 
IF model_exists = 0 THEN
    SEM_APIS.CREATE_SEM_MODEL('XCLOVER', 'XCLOVER_TPL','TRIPLE'); 
END IF;
COMMIT; 
END;
/
```